# Pytorch RuntimeError: "check_uniform_bounds" not implemented for 'Int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

Unable to set datatype for `torch.rand()` to `int`. The same line of code when set to `double`
`x = torch.rand(2,2,dtype=torch.double)` didnt throw any exception and worked perfectly. Any reason why `int` is throwing RuntimeError?

Python version: 3.9.6

Here is the code snippet:

```
import torch

x = torch.rand(2,2,dtype=torch.int)
y = torch.rand(2,2,dtype=torch.int)
print("x is", x)
print("y is", y)
z = torch.add(x,y)
print(z)
```

**Error Output:**

```
x = torch.rand(2,2,dtype=torch.int)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Training/main.py", line 4, in <module>
x = torch.rand(2,2,dtype=torch.int)
RuntimeError: "check_uniform_bounds" not implemented for 'Int'
```

Answer (score 4):

`torch.rand` is only implemented for **float types** and your code will trigger a runtime error in PyTorch if `int` is used:

[image]

```
torch.rand(*size, *, generator=None, out=None, dtype=None, layout=torch.strided, device=None, requires_grad=False, pin_memory=False)
```

*Returns a tensor filled with random numbers from a uniform distribution on the interval [0,1)*

*The shape of the tensor is defined by the variable argument size*

Links :

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_default_tensor_type.html#torch.set_default_tensor_type

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.rand.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want ints, you can use `torch.randint`[1]

[1] https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.randint.html